# External library: Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android, import, external

I am using [BetterSpinner](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1707) in my app.

I have simply included it like that:

```
compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
```

When I try to use it Android Studio even does not suggest to import the library and marks BetterSpinner red:

[image]

The code:

```
BetterSpinner textView = (BetterSpinner)
                findViewById(R.id.registration_spinner_stufe);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Where is the mistake that Android Studio does not import the BetterSpinner library into my Fragment class?

The solution

> "File" -> "Invalidate Caches..." -> "Invalidate and Restart"

did not work for me..

```
import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.BetterSpinner;
import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner;
```

Was ignored by Android Studio:

[image]

My complete grade file:

[app]

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.jublikon"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        sourceSets {
            main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/drawable/ic_action_search.png'] }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //Google Libraries
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
        compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
        compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1.6-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0'
        compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    }
```

[project]

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }
}
```

Comment: rebuild your project

Comment: I have cleaned my project and rebuilt after that. None of them helped

Comment: Did u try to add the imports manually?
`import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.BetterSpinner;`
`import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner;`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. I did not help. See my updated post

Comment: https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/issues/12

Comment: @piotrek1543 the post of your links says that I should add         mavenCentral() to repositories. There is three times repositories mentioned in the gradle file. I tried all of them but none did work for me. Where do I have to put mavenCentral()?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read the documentation and as far as I understood it, it is enough to add the mavenCentral() as I did in my updated post... But the class of BetterSpinner is still not importable in the classes. I would be very grateful if you could help me

Comment: @jublikon Have you solved this problem ?  I am facing the same .